# codeigniter 2 htaccess routing differences

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, apache2, codeigniter-2

Codeigniter v2.0 that was released on the 28th. I just setup a fresh installation and tried to remove the index.php from the url. I am using the same apache site-available configuration, htaccess, and codeigniter configuration.

Codeignter only loads the default controller defined in routes.php when I exclude the index.php.

For example

- http://myurl.com/welcome will load the welcome controller
- http://myurl.com/events will load the welcome controller
- but http://myurl.com/index.php/events will load the events controller

Here is my apache configuration for the site in question.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName myurl.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/myurl.com
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/myurl.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Here is my htaccess configuration

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

And here is my codeigniter configuration file found /var/www/mysite.com/application/config/config.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Base Site URL
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
 | WITH a trailing slash:
 |
 |  http://example.com/
 |
 | If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
 | path to your installation.
 |
 */
 $config['base_url']    = 'mysite.com';

 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Index File
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
 | something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
 | variable so that it is blank.
 |
 */
 $config['index_page'] = '';

 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | URI PROTOCOL
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
 | URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
 | If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
 |
 | 'AUTO'           Default - auto detects
 | 'PATH_INFO'      Uses the PATH_INFO
 | 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses the QUERY_STRING
 | 'REQUEST_URI'        Uses the REQUEST_URI
 | 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO

 */
  $config['uri_protocol']   = 'AUTO';

 /*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | URL suffix
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
 | For more information please see the user guide:
 |
 | http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */

 $config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] (without your question mark) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that changing the routing type from AUTO to REQUEST_URI made everything work.

```
 $config['uri_protocol']   = 'AUTO';
```

to

```
 $config['uri_protocol']   = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: When it comes to the uri_protocol all hosts are different so when there is something a miss with your urls and you are certain it's not your .htaccess rules, I recommend everyone mess around with the uri_protocol value. I've experienced issues where a value of PATH_INFO would only work on some servers while AUTO would work mostly on others.

Comment: REQUEST_URI was the required value on my MAMP localhost. Seems to be different from previous version of CI :(

Comment: I really liked that for previous CI versions I could leave uri_protocol set to AUTO and it would work almost everywhere. Now I'll have to mess around with different config values on test / production servers. Not that convenient... :(

Comment: For me it worked with changing to `PATH_INFO`. I use 2.0.3 now. In 1.7.3 it worked with `AUTO`...