# page not found on codeigeniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

maybe you can help me out here. I have an issue with my codeigniter setup. It's a fresh install and all I've done is this to the welcome controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    function test()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

other than that, everything is out of the box. Here is my .htaccess file that I am using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} callback
    RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Can't remember where I got this from, but it's working on other versions of codeigniter. so right now, when I got to this url:

http://myurl.com/welcome/index

the pages comes up fine, but when I got to this url, I get:

http://myurl.com/welcome/test

I get page not found. For some reason it seems that I need to load a view file for the page to be found. I've done multiple ci installations, and this is the first time I've had so many issues.

The reason why I need echo to work like this is because I use it to spit out lots of information using print_r, so I don't always use a controller. I have another problem with this installation, but that's for another question.

thanks guys!

### Update

What's really odd about this issue is that this doesn't happen in firefox, but it happens in ie and chrome. I've never seen anything like this before.

### update

Unfortunately I read the error wrong... doh! When I hit the welcome/test, I get an "Oops! This link appears to be broken.", not a 404 error. And on ie I get the

> The webpage cannot be found   HTTP 404
>   Most likely causes: •There might be a
>   typing error in the address. •If you
>   clicked on a link, it may be out of
>   date.
>        What you can try: 
>        Retype the address.
>
> ```
>  Go back to the previous page. 
>
>  Go to  and look for the information you want.  
>
>  More information
> ```
>
> This error (HTTP 404 Not Found) means
>   that Internet Explorer was able to
>   connect to the website, but the page
>   you wanted was not found. It's
>   possible that the webpage is
>   temporarily unavailable.
>   Alternatively, the website might have
>   changed or removed the webpage. For
>   more information about HTTP errors,
>   see Help.

If I try to hit a page that doesn't exist, I get 404 errors which is what I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Johnathan, I'm glad I got to fix your problem.  All you had to do was enable apache's mod rewrite.

```
a2enmod rewrite /etc/init.d/apache2
reload
```

Because you didn't have apache's mod rewrite, code igniter must have screwed up some rewrite rules and messed up your form data on post back.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your uri_protocol to 

`$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";`

[codeigniter 2 htaccess routing differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848589/codeigniter-2-htaccess-routing-differences)

Here is my HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
```

```
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

</IfModule>

Comment: I suggest you try playing around with the uri_protocols... CI2 has been pretty uncooperative with these settings...