# Remove "index.php" from URL - Codeigniter

Tags: apache, macos, codeigniter, osx-snow-leopard

I've looked in the documentation of Codeigniter of removing the `index.php` from the URL when accessing different views, the code shows how to remove it with apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, when I go to `http://localhost/code/home`, I get this:

> The requested URL /code/home was not found on this server.

But accessing `http://localhost/code/index.php/home` works just fine, how come it isn't working for me?

I'm on a Mac OS X Snow Leopard using the `Sites` directory: `/Users/~myusername~/Sites/code`, and I'm not using any software, i.e. MAMP, XAMPP.

**EDIT**

For the `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -k restart -S` command, I get this:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server code.local (/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:146)
         port 80 namevhost code.local (/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:146)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: checkout this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848589/codeigniter-2-htaccess-routing-differences/4867638#4867638

Comment: Yeah, it's stored in that directory.

Comment: The output from "localhost/code" and "code.local" is expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make "http://localhost/code" your web root as 'code.local' (in my example).
Assuming that your setup on Mac OS X Snow Leopard is the same as mine.

You should add the following lines to "/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/~myusername~/Sites/code"
    ServerName "code.local"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/code-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/code-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure that it is uncommented in "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then you add code.local to your "/etc/hosts" which should look like this

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       code.local
```

Then restart your apache "/usr/sbin/apachectl -k restart".

You might need to sudo if you are not a super user.
Hope this helps.

EDIT:
To check if your virtual host works. Run this
   sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -k restart -S
To see if code.local has been added as one of your virtual hosts.

Then try accessing code.local/index.php/welcome and code.local/welcome to check if it works.

Comment: I end up getting `The requested URL /code was not found on this server.`

Comment: ah, instead of code.local/code, it should be `http://code.local/home` as your Sites/code is now the web root. Hope it works now.

Comment: The domain works, but `code.local/add` doesn't work, but `code.local/code/index.php/add` works. I get an error: `The requested URL /code/add was not found on this server.`

Comment: Ah, check your `application/config/config.php`.
I just set the following to blank.
`$config['base_url']  = '';`

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: By the way, check if `code.local/index.php/add` works. I'm wondering why `code.local/code/index.php/add` works when it shouldn't if `code.local` is now pointing to `/Users/~myusername~/Sites/code` instead of `/Users/~myusername~/Sites`.

Comment: I get `The requested URL /index.php/add was not found on this server.` for `code.local/index.php/add`.

Comment: Hmmm, that means `code.local` isn't `/Users/~myusername~/Sites/code`.

Comment: Can you run `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -k restart -S` and post here the results.

Comment: I got `NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts VirtualHost configuration: Syntax OK`.

Comment: Hmmm. So if `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
` has been in uncommented in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhost.conf` has been added with your virtual  host, can you try running `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k restart`. 

One thing note though that my `etc -> private/etc', same for `tmp -> private/tmp` and `var -> private/var` so also check if there are symbolic links for private. Else, you will need to omit the private folder from your hosts.

Comment: I just get `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`. I don't seem to have `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhost.conf` file somewhere. Also, I don't have any symbs with `private`.

Comment: Ah, can you check where your httpd.conf is located? And add the VirtualHost for code.local.

Comment: you can restart apache just by sending sudo apachectl restart

Comment: I added the virtualhost to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and still doesn't work.

Comment: Does running `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -k restart -S` still give you `NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts VirtualHost configuration: Syntax OK`

Comment: Nice, now we need to check if `code.local` = `/Users/~myusername~/Sites/code` by accessing this url `code.local/index.php/add` or the default `code.local/index.php/welcome` page for CodeIgniter.

Also you need to retain your original .htaccess from your question.
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 7):

Try this one

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried 3 before I got one to work

Answer (score 6):

To remove index.php from URL just add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

in the .htaccess file and move the .htaccess file near to index.php location

```
/var/www/CodeIgniter/index.php
/var/www/CodeIgniter/.htaccess
```

in config.php in config folder set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your CI installation is not into your document root you should add `RewriteBase /code/` to make it works.

This is my .htacces I use for a CI installation (this is little bit more elaborated than the one provided with the official documentation):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /code/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also make sure your httpd can handle .htaccess file. Check into httpd.conf if exists a line with `AllowOverride all` inside a `<Directory></Directory>` element

Hope this help

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I still don't know it's not working.

Comment: Did you check if you can override apache conf via .htaccess? You need something like this into your httpd.conf file: `<Directory /Users/> AllowOverride All</Directory>` (a restart is required)

Comment: Well then try RewriteRule with redirect [R] flag to check how the url is rewritten in fact (or aint at all).

Comment: But it did show you the rewritten url, didn't it? what was it then

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /code/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ code/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: `and I'm not using any software, i.e. MAMP, XAMPP` Just guessing you didnt enable directives option in your Mac (its disabled by default). Read this : http://clagnut.com/blog/350/

Comment: Okay, I've made changes now I get `Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /code/ on this server.` when navigating to `http://localhost/code`.

Comment: All directories in /code/ are forbidden to access. Why is this?

Comment: What changes you made? Share it here.

Comment: I changed the `~myusername~.conf` file in the `/apache2/users/` where I saw `AllowOverride None`, then changed it to `AllowOverride All`, then it made me forbidden to access.

Comment: You should did change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in main config, which was `httpd.conf`. For each user, based by link i gave above, it should be `AllowOverride AuthConfig`. If everything still goes wrong after you did all stuff in that referenced link, your best bet is to install MAMP.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, the things is.

1. htacces should be in the root of Codeigniter
2. Remove "Deny from all" in your htacces file.
3. Add the code on the post above

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /code/index.php/$1 [L]
```

You also need to modify the $config['index_page'] variable like this:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Please refer to my post at http://www.boxoft.net/2011/07/removing-index-php-from-codeigniter-2-0-2-url/ if you like.

Comment: Hmmm. That didn't work either... I'm sure yours would have worked.

Comment: It works well on my VPS running Debian 5. I'll try it on my Macbook later.

Answer (score 0):

in  `/etc/apache2/users/.conf`

try adding ..

```
<Directory "/Users/<your user name>/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and restart Apache to check results ..

Answer (score 0):

copy the .htaccess on your main codeigniter folder, mine was localhost/codeigniter/ and then change the {RewriteBase / to RewriteBase /codeigniter/}

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Create an .htacess file on the root folder of your web directory in codeigniter using the above code. You will be able to remove index.php if an url link contains index.php so it will display page with no error. Or if url doesn't contains index.php it will display the page without index.php in url.

Answer (score -1):

You all uri parts are rewrited, so it points to /index.php/code/home. The and good way to do it is to setup mapping eg. http://code.local to point to your /Users/~myusername~/Sites/code, then all your requests are resolved on the root level and everything will work as it should.

EDIT: Downvoters seem to be ignorants, but nevermind..

Here's what your code does now:

```
GET http://localhost/code/home
// rewritten to:
http://localhost/index.php/code/home
```

So like I said before the GOOD way would be host mapping so you get everything on the root level (which is GOOD as most likely you will have it this way on the production serv...) and that will do the trick withour changes in .htaccess.

Otherwise you may use Francesco's advice with RewriteBase, but a bit changed:

```
// Francesco's RewriteRule does this:
http://localhost/code/home
// rewritten to"
http://localhost/code/index.php/code/home
```

so simply change the RewriteRule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^code/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
// rewrites in your case to:
http://localhost/code/index.php/home
// which is what you wanted, aye?
```

Answer (score -1):

From the words of the CodeIgniter documentation

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:

example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php file.

you can find it here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: I guess you weren't reading my post properly, I HAVE included the guideline in my htaccess, but it's NOT working, hence I need a solution.