# Undefined property: Add::$cache - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

I'm experiencing a serious problem when I'm trying to use the [Memcached caching driver](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html#memcached) in Codeigniter. However, I cannot autoload the `cache` driver in this array:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'parser', 'common', 'cache');
```

If I remove the `cache`, the page loads, but if not the page shows blank with no error reporting (note, I have error reporting on and set to `E_ALL`).

Anyway, since I cannot load the `cache`, I added it to my created class `common`, and load it from there doing this:

```
class Common extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->driver('cache');
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting in errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Add::$cache
>
> Filename: controllers/add.php
>
> Line Number: 33 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/add.php
>
> Line Number: 33

Which `add.php` is this:

```
class Add extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array('page_title' => 'Add your listing');

        $this->load->view('overall_header', $data);

        $sql = "SELECT item_id,
                       item_name
                FROM " . ITEMS_TABLE . "
                WHERE item_visible = 1";

        $items_key = md5('query:' . $sql);

        $result = $this->cache->memcached->save($items_key); // this is line 33
    }
}
```

I need memcached to work for my Codeigniter application, I've tried using this custom made class from [github](http://github.com/tomschlick/memcached-library).

How can I get memcached to work, I have all the settings in the `application/config/memcached.php` properly set, but I guess that's not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure PHP has the memcached library loaded. PHP uses two type of library: memcache and memcached (note the D at the end). Codeigniter cache driver needs the memcached extension.

This driver is quite buggy. First, the default options are not loaded correctly so you need to make a config/memcached.php file

This is how my config/memcached.php looks:

```
<?php
$config['memcached'] = array(
        'hostname'  => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'      => 11211,
        'weight'    => 1
);
```

In my controller/model I load the driver in this way:

`$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcached', 'backup' => 'dummy'));`

So if memcached is not available, a dummy driver is loaded as fallback.

Take care that the current stable release of CodeIgniter (2.0.2) has another [bug](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/193/ci_cache_file) in the driver loader class. [Here the patch](https://bitbucket.org/patwork/codeigniter-reactor-my-modifications/changeset/3d780fd4a410/raw/codeigniter-reactor-my-modifications-3d780fd4a410.diff) I applied

After this fixes I got the driver working

Comment: Ah. Just found out I'm using Memcache... so there's no initial support for Memcache?

Comment: No, Cache_memcached.php uses memcached. Eventually you can write your own based on memcache

Comment: Hmm. Good idea. Thanks, just accepted your answer. Do you mind maybe answering this question if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809373/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter/6810884#6810884 Thanks :-)