# Removing the index.php file of codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
I am using a MAMP setup
I access my codeigniter welcome message as follows

http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter_2.0.2/index.php/welcome

the tutorial says

use a `.htaccess` file as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to get same message with

http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter_2.0.2/welcome

but I get a 404 not found error instead

Comment: Are you using Apache ? Also mention your OS.

Comment: There's so many of these questions on SO and CI Forums, CI's docs say it's simple but so many people have followed the instructions to the T and have had problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add RewriteBase on your htacces file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/CodeIgniter_2.0.2/"
...your rules here...
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to check your `httpd.conf`
Look for this line.. (the location may not be the same)

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Make sure it's uncommented. Then save your changes and restart apache server.
Also, make sure that the `.htaccess` file is in the same directory as your `index.php`.
It's usually the base directory of your CodeIgniter application.

EDIT:

Also forgot to mention that you need virtual hosts for this work seamlessly.
Argh, it seems your question is a repost. Here's another question but this is on a MAC OS X platform, with some detail on setting up your virtual hosts.
[Remove "index.php" from URL - Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809373/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

the last line should be

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

and not

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

the instructions you followed assume you are installing code igniter in the docroot, and not a subdirectory.  move all your files in /CodeIgniter_2.0.2 down a directory.

```
mv CodeIgniter_2.0.2/* .
```