# Codeigniter links, modify them

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter controller with the following `check()` function to check username and password.

```
http://localhost/prakash/modules/index.php/login/login/login/login/login/login/check
```

and every time I submit the form (from the view), the above link is generated. How can I overcome it. I could have used `redirect('login')` in the controller instead of `$this->load->view('login/login_form');` but in that way it wouldnt display the validation errors in the form.

**My Controller is**

```
function check(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            $this->load->view('login/login_form');
        }else{
            $this->load->model('loginModel');
            $query = $this->loginModel->validate();
            if($query){
                $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                               'is_logged_in' => true
                            );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                //redirecting to appropriate page 
                redirect('success');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('loginCheck','Username/Password Comination Incorrect!');
                redirect('login');
            }
        }

    }
```

**My view is**

```
<section class="main">
<form class="form-1" action="login/check" method="post">
    <?php echo "<p class=\"text-error\">{$this->session->flashdata('loginCheck')}</p>"; ?>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <p class="field">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username or email">
        <i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>
    </p>
        <p class="field">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <i class="icon-lock icon-large"></i>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-large"></i></button>
    </p>
</form>
</section>
```

Comment: ya every time i submit the form, one login is added infront of another..????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the action attribute of the form tag

Change

```
<form class="form-1" action="login/check" method="post">
```

To

```
<form class="form-1" action="/login/check" method="post">
```

Or better (if you are using the url helper)

```
<form class="form-1" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>login/check" method="post">
```

**Why is it happening?**

You are using a value that is relative to the `path` of the current url.

[HTML form action Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

**Example 1**

- Page

  - `http://www.example.com/`
- Form

  - `<form class="form-1" action="login/check" method="post">`
- Will post to

  - `http://www.example.com/login/check`

**Example 2**

- Page

  - `http://www.example.com/login/`
- Form

  - `<form class="form-1" action="login/check" method="post">`
- Will post to

  - `http://www.example.com/login/login/check`

**Example 3**

- Page

  - `http://www.example.com/login`
- Form

  - `<form class="form-1" action="/" method="post">`
- Will post to

  - `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: Ya thanks.. I used base URL `base_url()` but since my link was with index.php/login/check, it didnt worked and hence I used `site_url()` instead and it worked fine. However is there a good way to get rid of that index.php thing without bumping into nasty errors?

Comment: use .htaccess to redirect your requests to go through index.php if you are on apache.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809373/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter/12926692#12926692

Comment: to avoid concatening just put the path inside the function call.
    base_url('forum');