# Trying to remove index.php from URL in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to remove 'index.php' from the URL. I have tried by making

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

as

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

and

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

as

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and even tried with putting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

in .htaccess file, but it not working me. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What OS are you running? Windows? Ubuntu? OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, I just had inserted the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

and made 
`$config['index_page'] = '';`

in `config.php`

source: [Remove "index.php" from URL - Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809373/remove-index-php-from-url-codeignite)‌​r

Answered by: @Akhilraj N S

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've told me you're using Ubuntu...

1. Use the .htaccess configuration provided by Ayman.
2. Open a terminal and type `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable `mod_rewrite` on your machine.
3. Open 000-default with `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` and change the first occurence of `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Then restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Also use: `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: I know its not in proper format, but sorry, I cant answer my own questions because I don't have 10 reputations

Comment: +1 Now you will. Welcome to SO and enjoy CI.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 steps to remove index.php

1.Make below changes in application/config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Your Ci folder_name';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

2.Make .htacces file in your root directory using below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

3.Enable rewrite mode

i. First, initiate it with the following command:

**a2enmod rewrite**

ii. Edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

change the **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All**.

iii. Restart your server with the following command:

**sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart**

Answer (score 0):

This is the `.htaccess` file I always use. Works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteBase /project/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And should I keep the .htaccess file in application folder or the main project folder along with the application folder?

Comment: Keep it in the main project folder

Comment: It is still taking index.php

Comment: The `.htaccess` file should go in the root of your project folder. Right next to `application` and `system`; **not inside**.

Comment: Change `$config['uri_protocol']` back to `AUTO`.

Comment: I kept **.htaccess** file in project folder with application folder and also changed `$config['uri_protocol']` back to `AUTO`. Still it is not working. The URL appears like this [link](192.168.1.10/project/index.php/auth/login)

Comment: Your site is in a subdirectory... that said, try the updated `.htaccess` above.