# Remove index.php in CodeIgniter_2.1.4

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I am newbie in `Codeigniter` and trying to configure `Codeigniter`.

But i am unable to remove the `index.php` from url..

I changed the `.htaccess` file by following data which was given in userguide..

.htacess file contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and also changed the config file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

when i try to use the following url it results

**The requested URL /codeigniter/pages/view was not found on this server.**

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/pages/view
```

But i try with index.php in url..The page shown normally..

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/pages/view
```

**Is that .htaccess problem or i have to change some other files..**?

How to get rid of this problem?

Any Suggestions, acceptable.

**Update**

I am using ubuntu 3.10

I used the following command to enable module rewrite

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

The result as follows

```
  Module rewrite already enabled
```

I changed the permissions in

```
  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

As

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

After changing this file also no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer to my question.As the below .htaccess solved my problem..

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
     RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

    </IfModule>
```

Thanks to all..

Answer (score 0):

in your `httpd.conf` (on windows)

uncomment below line

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

in ubuntu 
 enable `mod_rewrite` using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Restart apache after making changes

Comment: tell me your operating system?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 3.10

Comment: check answer here it will solve your problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes

In config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

IN root .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|themes|utils|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It's not accepting in my ubuntu 3.10 and showing the same not found message

Comment: check this url in stack over flow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848325/trying-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned change the  setting. In your httpd config file find and change it like this

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">  # your DocumentRoot setting
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All  # default is None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```