# Removing index.php from codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

As of right now... This is the address that shows up when I run the application (and it's functional).

```
http://localhost:8888/baseline/index.php
```

If I take away the index.php it also works...

```
http://localhost:8888/baseline/
```

Running these two URI's is the same as running this function (which is functional).

```
http://localhost:8888/baseline/index.php/RegisterController/index
```

But if I try and run it without the index.php it's not functional...

```
http://localhost:8888/baseline/RegisterController/index
```

In my code I have 2 .htaccess files...

[image]

In the one that is right underneath "views" the code is this...

```
Deny from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

In the one underneath "system" the code is this...

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

# my url is http://localhost/arny
#RewriteBase /arny/
# set your own
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is what my config file looks like...
[image]

I've tried setting it from 'AUTO' to 'PATH_INFO' and haven't had any luck there.
There has been some talk about changing things on Apache but I have no idea how to do that.

I already checked out the following posts and wasn't able to get this working...

- [Remove index.php in codeigniter 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667226/remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-2-1-0)
- [Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2?rq=1)

I'm currently running...

- Netbeans 7.3.1
- CodeIgniter + Twitter BootStrap Boilerplate
- MAMP 2.2

Definitely let me know what other information I can provide and I'll re-edit the post. I definitely feel like an idiot after wading through these other pieces of documentation and still not being able to get this figured out.

Comment: Do you have ModRewrite enabled on your Apache server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing around with it as well. This is the one which works for me, and I fear touching it: ;) j/k

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(resources)/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(user_guide)/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]
```

It is located outside the application/system/user_guide directories. Resources is my own public folder, ignore that line.

I haven't touched the internal .htaccess files. They're what they were:

```
Deny from all
```

Hope this helps :)

Edit: Also check if you have the mod_rewrite enabled..

And this.. [Remove index.php in CodeIgniter_2.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225304/remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-2-1-4)

Comment: You are magical. This was the trick!
I also changed the other files to Deny from all as well and that is what did it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this under your system folder. This will allow the the extensions that you need passed through. ( Style Sheets , Scripts, etc... )

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` already allows static assets to pass through.  This is just adding an arbitrary list of paths that will not go to the front controller.